# search text in array using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I am very new to making search text in array some elements in array are in rangers i.e it cant be anything after certain text in this AA and A regex and I have multi-dimensional array and I want search text in each array . So I wrote something like this.I put AA* in array so only first 2 character should match and A* for only one character match.

```
arr = [
     ["AA*","ABC","XYZ"] ,
    ["A*","AXY","AAJ"]
    ]
    var text = "AA3";
    for ($i=0; $i<arr.length; $i++ ){
        var new_array = [];
        new_array = arr[$i];
        new_array.filter(function(array_element) {
              var result = new RegExp(array_element).test(text);
              
              if( result == true){
                console.log(arr[$i]);
          } 
            
          });
    }
```

So what i want is when **text = "AA3"** or anything after double A **AA[anything]** and the output should be first array which is ["AA*","ABC","XYZ"] but I am getting both array as output and when **text = "A3"** then output should be second array which is ["A*","POI","LKJ"] but I am getting both array.But if **text = "ABC"** or **text = "AAJ"** then it should output first array or second array respectively.I dont know anything about how to write regex or is there anyway I can implement this using any other method.
Thanks in advance any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

In short, the issue is "*"! The * found in the members of the set array is why you're getting the same array each time.

### Detailed Info

[Regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) is a one concept most developers find hard to understand (I am one of such btw ).

I'll start off with an excerpt intro to [Regexp on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> Regexp are patterns used to match character combinations in strings - MDN

With that in mind you want to understand what goes on with your code.
When you create a Regex like `/A*/` to test `"AA3"`, what would be matched would be `A`, `AA`, etc. This is a truthy in javascript. You would want a more stricter matching with [`^` or `$`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) or strictly [matching a number with `\d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes).

I rewrote your code as a function below:

```js
arr = [
    ["AA*", "ABC", "XYZ"],
    ["A*", "AXY", "AAJ"],
];

findInArray(arr, "AA3") // prints both array
findInArray(arr, "AAJ") // prints second array
findInArray(arr, "ABC") // prints first array

function findInArray(array, value) {
    return array.filter((subArray) =>
        subArray.some((item) => {
            const check = new RegExp(value);
            return check.test(item);
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: `findInArray(arr, "AA3")` doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

The problem lies in the fact you use each of the strings as a regex.

- For a string with a `*` wildcard, this evaluates to zero or more matches of the immediately preceding item, which will always be `true`.
- For a string consisting solely of alphanumerics, this is comparing a string to itself, which similarly will always give `true`.
- For strings containing characters that constitute the regex's syntax definition, this could result in errors or unintended behavior.

[MDN article on RegExp quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)

#### Rewrite

Assumptions:

- The value with a `*` wildcard is always only at the `0`<sup>th</sup> position,
- There is only one such wildcard in its string,
- The question mentions that for `text = 'AAJ'` only the 2<sup>nd</sup> array shall be returned, but both the `AA*` from the 1<sup>st</sup> array and `AAJ` from the 2<sup>nd</sup> would seem to match this `text`.
  As such, I assume the wildcard can only stand for a number (as other examples seem to suggest).

Code:

```js
const abc = (arrs, text) => {
  return arrs.filter(arr => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${arr[0].replace('*', '\\d+')}$`);
    return regex.test(text) || arr.includes(text);
  })
}



const arr = [
  ["AA*", "ABC", "XYZ"],
  ["A*", "AXY", "AAJ"]
];

console.log(
`1=[${abc(arr, "AA3")}]
2=[${abc(arr, "ABC")}]
3=[${abc(arr, "AAJ")}]`);
```